# Java EJB JNDI Beans Lookup Failed

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, ejb, jndi

I have the following structure in place:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.screening</groupId>
  <artifactId>screening</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>Screening Java Parent</name>

  <modules>
     <module>Module1</module>
     <module>Module2</module>
  </modules>

<dependencies>
<!-- multiple dependency here -->
<dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The above is a pom that is the parent of the below modules:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.screening</groupId>
        <artifactId>screening</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.screening</groupId>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>Module1</name>
</project>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.screening</groupId>
        <artifactId>screening</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.screening</groupId>
    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>Module2</name>
</project>
```

I have some stateless beans such as:

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class ProcessorBean implements Processor {
     // implemented methods
}
```

I am using an embedded EJBContainer for Glassfish for unit tests. When accessing them using the following:

```
Processor processor = (Processor) container.getContext().lookup(new String("java:global/classes/ProcessorBean!com.screening.processor.Processor");
```

It works correctly. The issue is that when I include Module 2 as part of Module 1 the unit tests fail by throwing the following Exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/classes/ProcessorBean! com.screening.processor.Processor' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: classes]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at com.screening.processor.ProcessorBeanTest.setUpClass(ProcessorBeanTest.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray (ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: classes
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.resolveContext(TransientContext.java:252)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:172)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup (SerialContextProviderImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:101)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:430)
... 25 more
```

Having a look at the classes Apache Maven does generate this. I am not sure how to fix this. This only happens once I include Module 2 as part of Module 1.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.screening</groupId>
        <artifactId>screening</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.screening</groupId>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>Module1</name>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency> <!-- Taking this out it works -->
           <groupId>com.screening</groupId>
           <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
           <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
   <dependencies>
 </project>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: The classes are generated and can be seen.

Comment: Have you found any workarounds?